# Hadoop distcp with file list

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, distcp, s3distcp

I would like to use distcp to copy a list of files (> 1K files) into hdfs. I have already stored list of files in local directory, now can I use -f  to copy all files? if yes what is the format do I have to maintain in my files list file? or is there any other better way?

Comment: Hi, you cannot use distcp to copy files from LFS (local file system) to HDFS. The correct command is -copyFromLocal <source> <destination>

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use distcp if your use-case is copying data from local filesystem (say Linux) to HDFS. You can simply use `hdfs dfs -put` command for the same. Here is the syntax.

`hdfs  dfs  -put  /path/to/local/dir/*  /path/on/hdfs/`

e.g.

`hdfs  dfs  -mkdir  /user/hduser/destination-dir/`

`hdfs  dfs  -put  /home/abc/mydir/*  /user/hduser/destination-dir/`

You have created a file containing list of file paths but that is not at all needed. It's mainly used (for distcp) when you are copying data from one cluster to other cluster